# Is it possible for the Flutter App to be able to unlock and lock a car door?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Is it possible for the Flutter App to be able to unlock and lock a car door? What are the things I need to start with?

Does it include the functionalities of Telematics technology?

Answer (score 1):

With flutter we can build a mobile/web app which alone can't control the car.
Briefly you will need (that's a simplified list):

- A telematics IoT device which is capable of open/close car via CAN
- A MQTT broker that can receive/send messages from/to telematics device
- An API which can be consumed by your flutter app in order to communicate with the in-car telematics device.

Answer (score -1):

Look at all the available packages at `pub.dev`. Maybe one provides the functionalities you need.

By right we only accept programming questions here. You write some code and you get stumped. You show your current code and we help you debug/fix the code.

Answer (score -1):

With a quick google I was able to find this as the first result:
https://github.com/rrrovalle/tesla-car-app

Seems possible. Just try your luck googling and looking on pub.dev.
Maybe there's a package. Maybe you have to implement it yourself or use native packages in the platform channels.

There's probably a solution. But you will have to do some research yourself.